# Custom joins entitys on Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, join, ejb, one-to-many

We have a Hibernate based system with Annotations.

Our entities have a custom property DELETED.
We have to select non deleted entities with non deleted sub-entities.
How can we can do it?

Little sample for describe the situation:

```
GenericEntity {
    ...
    @Basic
    @Column(name = DELETED)
    protected Boolean deleted = false;


    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = LOCATION, nullable = false)
    protected Location location;        
}
```

Location extends GenericEntity entity, and also has a DELETED property.

How can we select some not deleted GenericEntities with non deleted Locations?

Comment: Thx for anses.
It is good:
   where g.deleted = false and g.location.deleted = false

But, can we do it automatically, may be with some annotations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This HQL should work

```
select * from GenericEntity g where g.deleted = false and g.location.deleted = false
```

Answer (score 0):

Note by using an alias as Aaron has done (g) you can access the entities properties.